# PHP: How to fetch data from a bound query?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to bind id to a SQL query and fetch the result and store it in a variable. However the following code doesnt seem to work.

```
$prep_query = "SELECT seller FROM items_list WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_query);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$itemId);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->fetch(); // I should get the name of the seller
```

Could somebody explain what I am doing wrong? Some additional reading sources would be nice too.

Comment: define *"doesn't seem to work"*

Comment: `$result` is empty string, although the query `SELECT seller FROM items_list WHERE id = 7` works fine in PHPMyAdmin console. The `$itemId` variable has 7 in it. I `echo`ed and checked.

Comment: if it works fine in your console, then something is failing you. PHP/MySQL, could be anything. If you're not using the same MySQL to connect with as per your query, then that would do it. Check for errors ;-)

Comment: try this add  after $stmt->execute();

   $stmt->bind_result($seller);
   $stmt->fetch();
   printf("Seller %s\n", $seller);

Comment: @JasonK It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the bindParam method of PDO object, you need to name your parameter in your query like this

```
$prep_query = "SELECT seller FROM items_list WHERE id = :i";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_query);
$stmt->bindParam(':i',$itemId);
```

You can find the PDO documentation here http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php